# Chained Drop Down Select List Code -- Connection Data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on adapting a chained drop-down feature that I found online to my site. Some of the code that I found online is below. One issue is that I'm having trouble making sense of the line that reads `var connection = selected.data('connection');` Is the connection attribute something that is common to jquery? Or is it set somewhere in the code? If so, where in the code is this set?

```
$(function(){

    var questions = $('#questions');

    function refreshSelects(){
        var selects = questions.find('select');

        // Improve the selects with the Chose plugin
        selects.chosen();

        // Listen for changes
        selects.unbind('change').bind('change',function(){

            // The selected option
            var selected = $(this).find('option').eq(this.selectedIndex);
            // Look up the data-connection attribute
            var connection = selected.data('connection');

            // Removing the li containers that follow (if any)
            selected.closest('#questions li').nextAll().remove();

            if(connection){
                fetchSelect(connection);
            }

        });
    }

    var working = false;

    function fetchSelect(val){

        if(working){
            return false;
        }
        working = true;

        $.getJSON('ajax.php',{key:val},function(r){

            var connection, options = '';

            $.each(r.items,function(k,v){
                connection = '';
                if(v){
                    connection = 'data-connection="'+v+'"';
                }

                options+= '<option value="'+k+'" '+connection+'>'+k+'</option>';
            });

            if(r.defaultText){

                // The chose plugin requires that we add an empty option
                // element if we want to display a "Please choose" text

                options = '<option></option>'+options;
            }

            // Building the markup for the select section

            $('<li>\
                <p>'+r.title+'</p>\
                <select data-placeholder="'+r.defaultText+'">\
                    '+ options +'\
                </select>\
                <span class="divider"></span>\
            </li>').appendTo(questions);

            refreshSelects();

            working = false;
        });

    }

    $('#preloader').ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    // Initially load the product select
    fetchSelect('productSelect');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at jQuery.data() function. This function allows you to store and retrieve arbitrary data associated with the specified element.

In your example "option" has some attribute of the name connection. Looking at the code it seems that the attribute connection is used to make a decision about which of the next link to select in the chain.

Comment: I understood that, but nowhere in the code is the data() method used to assign information with the attribute name 'connection' to the option object.

Comment: data-* are HTML5 data attributes. They are set as data-connection in the code but can be fetched as data()  More info: http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/html5_data-_attributes_are_great_and_you_know_it.html

Comment: Goodness my friend, read your code connection = '';
                if(v){
                    connection = 'data-connection="'+v+'"';
                }                                                                       options+= '<option value="'+k+'" '+connection+'>'+k+'</option>';

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But doesn't your link say we have to use the attr() method and not the data() method to retrieve data stored using the data-* syntax?

Comment: That link was to give you more info about the HTML5 data attributes. with new jquery updates, you can use data()